# Angular, custom decorator that add a new component in the actual component

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator in angular to add a spinner on top of the actual component.

So my actual component is doing any request to the API and I'm putting the decorator on top of the method.

Ideally it should look like this.

```
export function loaderDecorator() {
  return function (target: Object, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function (...args: any) {

        //create a new HttpSpinnerComponent and append it to the target component

      try {
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        //delete HttpSpinner component
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        //delete HttpSpinner component
      }
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

But after looking up for a while now I can't find or do anything working. So I was wondering if maybe you knew how i could get access to the angular component factory from my decorator or any other way to put a spinner component on top of my actual loading component (I tried with interceptors and service but can't manage to make it work too)

Comment: I achieved this effect in a different way. Wrapping anything (what you call actual component) in a configurable loader component, like this: `<loading [isLoading]="isLoading">.....</loading>`. The `<loading>` component overlays the enclosed content with a spinner whenever `isLoading` is `true`. The content enclosed in the `<loading>` element is rendered inside a `<ng-content>` element. This is an abbreviated explanation, hopefully clear enough to get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't support custom decorator on Components.

> We don't support them because there's a big conceptual mismatch - the Angular compiler is trying to statically transform classes according to their Angular annotations, but custom decorators are attempting to arbitrarily change the shape of that class at runtime.

[See this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48276#issuecomment-1332611012)

Comment: The decorator is on the method in the component, even tho it's not supported I'm able to interact with the main Component